# Error when using a macro expansion for function declarations

Tags: c++, windows, dll, macros, loadlibrary

I'm trying to create a proxy class for delayed load of a shared library.

One of the API function of the library is:

```
int AttachCWnd(CWnd* pControl);
```

So, I created a macro to easily declare and route calls from the proxy class to the library:

```
class CLibProxy {
public:
  typedef int  (*tAttachCWnd)(CWnd*);
  tAttachCWnd m_fAttachCWnd;
};

#define DECL_ROUTE(name, ret, args) \
  ret CLibProxy::name args \
  { \
    if (m_hDLL) \
      return m_f##name (args); \
    return ret(); \
  }

DECL_ROUTE(AttachCWnd, int, (CWnd* pControl));
```

But compilation fails on VS2010:

```
error C2275: 'CWnd' : illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: View the [preprocessed source](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7695258f1111bdcc) and it should become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obvious mistake. Calling m_fAttachCWnd should not include the type declaration, but only the arguments:

```
return m_fAttachCWnd (CWnd* pControl);
```

should become

```
return m_fAttachCWnd (pControl);
```

Thanks @chris.